# Select last N rows that match C condition (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table such as

| i.id | t.status |
| --- | --- |
| 140 | 'DONE' |
| 140 | 'RUNNING' |
| 140 | 'READY' |
| 137 | 'FAILED' |
| 137 | 'DONE' |
| 137 | 'DONE' |
| 123 | 'DONE' |
| 123 | 'DONE' |

Which is a result of this query:

```
SELECT i.id, t.status
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN tasks AS t
ON i.id = t.item_id
WHERE project_id=2046
ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

I want to somehow get the id 137, because it's the first id in which all three rows (tasks) are either 'DONE' or 'FAILED'. I don't know how to continue.

The way I see it is, as the title of the question say, find the first 3 rows that have the same id and in which the status is either 'DONE' or 'FAILED', and then give me the id.

Comment: Are there *always* three rows per `id` can there be more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know the ID's matching the criteria, it's quite easy. If you want all data, I suggest using this as a subquery, and adjust your current query to have their IDs in its result (`WHERE i.id IN (...)`).

So first of all, we want to exclude all non-relevant rows:
`WHERE t.status = 'DONE' OR t.status = 'FAILED'`

After this, we want to count how many rows are still left. For this we need a `COUNT(t.status)`, and we need to specify what to group by: `GROUP BY i.id`. (NOTE: adding the `COUNT` to the `SELECT` part is optional.)

Once we have this, we want to check which IDs meet our >=3 criterium using `HAVING COUNT(t.status) >= 3`.

Your end query will be:

```sql
SELECT i.id
FROM items i
INNER JOIN tasks t
ON i.id = t.item_id
WHERE project_id=2046 AND (t.status = 'DONE' OR t.status = 'FAILED')
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(t.status) >= 3;
```

Hope this answers your question.